# Pivoting programatically and carrying color information in summary of Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

We have a base table that looks like this, in our main sheet called "MainData".

We would like to summarize it in a new worksheet. The summary needs to be by time, in a program management mode, where the "When" becomes the main view, in the following way. We could technically get a version of the top part of the table via Pivot, but that forces a new worksheet. We would like this entire view to be in our own second sheet of choice which we can call "Summary".

Not sure where to begin with this. The `GETPIVOTDATA` command seems a more convenient way to control how the pivot shows without forcing a worksheet, but it's the itemization of colours etc that is confusing. In each week's listing below that week column, we'd like to show the items but their cell needs to be coloured by the Status that item is in.

Not looking for ready made solutions (although I won't revolt if that's shared), just looking for pointers for which functions to look for. Thanks muchly!

Comment: It feels like a good starting point would be to do a transpose of UNIQUE on C2:C to get your column headers. I feel like much of the rest of it could then be done with QUERY. (color might be hard)

Comment: Thank you Jeremy. You're right and the Transpose is helpful. There's some more help below, but I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution:

It's quite a task... :)
I have build working solution for you.

[Go to this link to grab this (2 sheets - data and report)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ua36vD9JLiypydQegZRgvOXJG7iR25sPde9eydp3ks0/edit#gid=374368538)

## Explanation:

### Data sheet:

I added an extra column to source data - we will need this column in further query (you can hide this column)

```
={"Rep Desc";ArrayFormula(if(A2:A<>"";"Count of "&A2:A;))}
```

[image]

### Report sheet:

I added 2 extra columns (A:B) (you can hide them later) to explain better what is going on. There are 4 main parts to this solution - you are able to pack all of them into one formula, but for sake of clarification I left them separate.

**Part 1 Numbers of "Open / Closes / Attn"**

This is simple query - we use extra column in data source to have desire description (Count of... instead just Attn, Closed, etc)

```
=QUERY({INDIRECT($A$1)};$B$1;1)
```

string to query

```
select Col5, count(Col4) where Col1 is not null group by Col5 pivot Col3 label Col5 ''
```

[image]

**Part 2 - "Sum of Point"**

Its Query again put into next query to remove headers + "Sum of Points" as an extra column (using inline array - `{}`):

```
={"Sum of Points"\QUERY(QUERY({INDIRECT($A$1)};B5;1);"select * offset 1";0)}
```

string to query

```
select sum(Col4) where Col1 is not null pivot Col3
```

[image]

**Part 3 - "Features"**

It is quite complicated... If I find more time I will describe what is going on here... but for now just code:

```
  =QUERY(

transpose(ArrayFormula(SPLIT(
transpose(SPLIT(
TEXTJOIN("^";1;transpose(
{SPLIT(join(" @@ ";transpose(query(transpose(QUERY({INDIRECT($A$1)};$B$9;1));"select Col1 offset 1";0)));" @";0;1);
QUERY(ArrayFormula(IF(TRANSPOSE(query(transpose(QUERY({INDIRECT($A$1)};$B$9;1));"select * offset 1";0))<>"";
query(QUERY({INDIRECT($A$1)};$B$9;1);"select Col1";0);""));"select * offset 1";0)}
))
;"@ ";0;1))
;"^")))
;
"select * offset 1";0)
```

[image]

**Part 4 - Conditional formatting**

For range D9:H apply 3 rules with corresponding color :

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("data!$A:$A");MATCH(D9;INDIRECT("data!$B:$B");0);1)="Open"

=INDEX(INDIRECT("data!$A:$A");MATCH(D9;INDIRECT("data!$B:$B");0);1)="Closed"

=INDEX(INDIRECT("data!$A:$A");MATCH(D9;INDIRECT("data!$B:$B");0);1)="Attn"
```

[image]

## OK?

Is that what you were going to achieve?

Again - this is working copy for you:

[Go to this link to grab this (2 sheets - data and report)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ua36vD9JLiypydQegZRgvOXJG7iR25sPde9eydp3ks0/edit#gid=374368538)

Comment: Thank you so much Grzegorz! This is much more than I was expecting. I wish I could give +1000 for this one. Thank you thank you.

Comment: Just one more thing, which is a nice to have, not a must have. Would it be possible to group the colors in the listing by week? The last step. So all greens together first, then all yellows, then all reds..?

Comment: Actually, a different question: the complex query to list items by the Week ("When") seems to hard code where it starts. If I wanted to put this query in a sheet of its own, it doesn't seem to work as the listing starts from about the 5th or 6th column, and there's no heading of Week. What in this code do I need to alter so we can get the listing from column 1, and also get headings of its own? This way I can create my own sheet with all the input from "data" worksheet again and format this one differently. Thanks so much for this help (I'm slowly deciphering this code).

Comment: Could you provide more complex sample of your real sheet?

Comment: FYI, my comments and help needed are in red text. Many thanks!

Comment: ok, this is working file for you - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13DzSNu00hHfysEAHsczegtVmUMSTJH30tY5BkjJjuNs/edit?usp=sharing - fixes: Data!E:E - format as text not numbers nor automatic; formulas format I use in example was not US - changed that in your file; "Sprint Items By Week" need numbers in Data!F:F so I hve change empt to zero and TBA to -1 (I hope you can live with it :).

Comment: Thank you so much GM. However, this file seems to stop at row 11 max for each week. How can I ensure that it covers all the items in the actual file, which follows the format in my sample but is actually much larger -- it has over 150 items. Ifyou could just let me know what to edit in that formula. Thanks!

Comment: Which part stops at 11 row?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179391/discussion-between-khom-nazid-and-grzegorz-mogilewski).